# gwt super dev mode debug in chrome not showing debug values of variables in source maps

Tags: debugging, gwt

I can load my project in gwt super dev mode but can't comfortably get debug values like in eclipse. How to get it work and see the correct java variable values in chrome?

I've configured the project according to:

http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html

Basically I can see the values in some kind of javascript interpretations which is far from eclipse java - not comfortable to find the values and see the structure of collections ant etc...

Answer (score 5):

Browser debugger can only interpret Javascript so it only shows the values of corresponding javascript variables(not the exact java variables). These variable names are slightly different from java variable names. You can see those variables in the scope section.

[image]